# How to show the Current date in textBox using Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can any one tell me how can I print the `current data` in this format `(dd-mm-yyyy)` ?

I am using this command, but it is not working:

```
protected void TextBoxStartDate_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
              TextBoxStartDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
           // TextBoxStartDate.Text = DateTime.Now();
        }
```

I want `autofill` textbox with a `current date`

Comment: this will populate your textbox when you change your value of textbox

Answer (score 6):

> how can i print the current data in this format (dd-mm-yyyy)

Lower **mm** means minutes..!!

You can use this format:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Change your code like this:

```
protected void TextBoxStartDate_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    TextBoxStartDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
       // TextBoxStartDate.Text = DateTime.Now();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this `TextBoxStartDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();` on `PageLoad`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   TextBoxStartDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

here is my ASP.cs code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxStartDate" runat="server" ontextchanged="TextBoxStartDate_TextChanged" Width="150px" Height="16px"  ></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Not Working :( @zzzzz

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxStartDate" runat="server" ontextchanged="TextBoxStartDate_TextChanged" Width="150px" Height="16px"  ></asp:TextBox>

Comment: Code behind protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   TextBoxStartDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
}

Comment: @Ismail; you have not added the `protected` and `void` access specifier in your code behind

Answer (score 0):

You can do it on you page Load event.

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox1.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
        }
```

Comment: Not Working my project is not online or not on any hosting server

Comment: System.DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(); this will catch your host machine datetime.

Answer (score 0):

You can write it on `Page_Load` event to get the [Current Date Time](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now(v=vs.110).aspx)

The Code will be:-

You  must also have namespace included in your code,

aspx and cs:-

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxStartDate" runat="server" OnTextChanged="TextBoxStartDate_TextChanged" Width="150px" Height="16px" ></asp:TextBox>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
 {
     TextBoxStartDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
 }
```

Also as per your code, you need to add `onTextChanged` event in your code-behind

```
protected void TextBoxStartDate_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do something here
}
```

**UPDATE**

You will get something like below in your textbox when you load your page

[image: Date Textbox]

Comment: Not Working :( @Coder

Comment: can you sow what you tried ?? both aspx and cs code/